# Spring and default settings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have quite complex situation and hope someone will help me with it.

I have several maven modules, common setup is two base modules with a standalone module that requires first two; they all together make an uberjar with a microservice, and i'll have something around 10 microservices built like that in current project. The problem is that i want to build an automatic system which will provide my modules with default settings in case `.properties` files miss some of configuration options. The most easy way would be define `@Component`-annotated settings providers classes and scan container for such components, but properties have to be set on early stages of container initialization, so i can't locate such components.

So.
I need somehow to automate loading of particular classes during Spring container startup, but don't have a clue how to do this *properly*. Of course i can scan whole classpath for implementations of particular interface, but i feel that this is terribly bad idea. Any clues on how to handle this gracefully?

Comment: "Auto-magical" things are fragile. Is is really worth the time and complexity to build this rather than throw an error for missing settings so you can catch it in testing?

Comment: @billc.cn yes, i'm working alone now but will have couple of apprentices in a month, and i want to have as less "set this to that, tweak a little thing there, call me once again if this doesn't work" as possible. I want everything to be *just working*, and i can't tell there's huge space for errors - check for default constructor of provider, if there's no such thing, speak it out in logs, move forward and catch error in testing.